# Google Earth Engine - Dynamic Visualization Parameters

Tags: google-earth-engine, visualisation, reducers

I made a script that calculates the maximum NDVI values of the last 100 days of an area. Therefore, depending on WHEN you run it, the resulting image.
Is there any straight straightforward method to achieve this?
I tried a image reducer and then parse it to the visualization parameters, but can't make it work.

Best would be to get real-time "Stretch by XXX standard deviations", or "min-max". 
How do I enter these values to the visualization parameters?

```
var newDate = new Date();
var dateto = ee.Date(newDate);
var datefrom = dateto.advance(-120, 'day');

var geometry = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2018/States').filterMetadata('NAME','equals','Nebraska');
var collectionNDVI = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
                .filterDate(datefrom ,dateto)
                .filterBounds(geometry)
                .select("NDVI");
var aoi= geometry.geometry().bounds()
var NDVI = collectionNDVI.select(['NDVI']).max().clip(aoi)

var STD= NDVI.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
  geometry: NDVI.geometry(),
  scale: 250,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});
print(STD)
var nbrParams = {min: 1, max: 5000 , palette: ['red', 'yellow', 'green']};
Map.addLayer(NDVI,nbrParams, "maxNDVI COMBINED")
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The visualization parameters need to be client-side, while the results from `reduceRegion()` are server-side. You can turn a server-side to client-side by calling `evaluate()`, passing a callback function. Sure, you can call `getInfo()` too, which is a bit simpler, but that blocks your interface.

```
ndvi
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev().combine(ee.Reducer.minMax(), '', true),
    geometry: geometry.geometry(),
    scale: 250,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  })
  .evaluate(function (stats) {
    var stdDev = stats.NDVI_stdDev
    var min = stats.NDVI_min
    var max = stats.NDVI_max
    var visParams = {
      min: min,
      max: max,
      palette: ['red', 'yellow', 'green']
    }
    Map.addLayer(ndvi, visParams, "maxndvi COMBINED")
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/12b2fe061469da85b54d757fcf31c6b8

Comment: It helps, but I still can't select XXX standard deviations

Comment: How would you want that stretch to work exactly?

Comment: did it! Replace ee.Reducer.minMax() for mean() and then replaced:                                                   var min = stats.EVI_mean - stats.EVI_stdDev *2                                                        var max = stats.EVI_mean + stats.EVI_stdDev *2